# Multiple uploadify in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, uploadify

I'm try to upload the file for a list of input like that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCNXF/) how can add the uploadify jQuery to this control and upload the image codeigniter. and i'm try to the below code refered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995183/uploadify-multiple-buttons-one-page)

```
jQuery(".file_upload").each(function() {
   jQuery(this).uploadify({
      height        : 30,
      swf           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      uploader      : '/script/uploadify/uploadify.php',
      width         : 120
   });
});
```

but it's not working to me. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **HTML** should be like,

```
<!-- Use file type instead of text -->
<input type="file" name="test1[]" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="test1[]" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="test1[]" class="file_upload"/>
```

And use your **code** on submit of **form**

Comment: sorry,upload the image in ajax only.